# Sitecore 9 Federated Authentication on CM server - Single Logout

Tags: federated-authentication

I am using sitecore 9 federated authentication feature to authenticate user through third party, i need to implement single logout from sitecore CMS.

what is the configuration needs to be done to allow single logout from CMS?